# How to Clear Log in Attendance Machine

Tags: c#

I have developed Attendance Management System using ZkemKeeper SDK in C# Code.I would like to know how to clear Log in Machine for Specific Date Range.
I have tried ClearGLog() mothod,but its clear all log in Machine.Please advise how to do that....

Comment: Please show us your existing code. What makes you believe that ZkemKeeper supports that feature? Why do you want to clear log entries?

Comment: Actually I am going to store Today's Log Data in sql table,It take time When its read all log data from machine,so I would like to clear old log data except today's log data...

Comment: See the below code for clearing log data                                 axCZKEM1.ClearGLog(Convert.ToInt32(StrMachineNo));

Comment: Please help........

Comment: You cannot clear the logs to the specific time. Either you have to clear all or retain all

Answer (score 0):

Please follow write these line after connecting bio-matric device

```
if (IsConnecetd == true)
{
  bool delete = axCZKEM1.ClearGLog(dwMachineNumber);

  if (delete == true)
  {
    // Deleted Successfully 
  }
}
```